# projection of the data along the 1st k principal components

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, projection, principal-component-analysis

I'm a final year maths undergrad doing a course in multivariate data analysis, but I'm really struggling with the linear algebra. In particular the “projection of the data along the 1st k principal components” is mentioned in the notes as
[image]

but the projection of a vector along a vector is defined as
[image]

To me, given the projection of one vector along another vector is itself a vector, the “projection of the data along the 1st k principal components”, could not be stored in matrix alone, but would have to be in an k by (n by p or p by n) array. The matrix $XV_k$ does contain the scaling factors for every single data point along the 1st k principal components, but it’s got nothing to do with directionality. Can anyone explain what I'm not getting here?
Cheers,
Douglas

Comment: Here's a link to a similar question which has been answered:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565685/projecting-data-onto-a-vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get it right, the confusion comes from semantics.

I think the word "projection" used in the PCA / machine learning field is subtly different from the 2nd projection you used in geometry / linear algebra (projecting 3d points to 2d).

In PCA language, the projection usually just referred to the "projection coefficient" or signed length of projection along the vector $v_k$. You can think of it like a "coordinate" value on the basis vector $v_k$.

To compare them,

- In PCA, projection refers to the scalar $x^Tv_k$ (assuming unit vector $v_k$.
- In geometry, projection refers to the vector $(x^Tv_k)v_k$.